# Firefox prompts me to choose save or open Options even after setting preference

Tags: selenium, firefox

```
   string testDir = System.IO.Path.Combine(TestContext.CurrentContext.TestDirectory);
        FirefoxProfile fxprofile = new FirefoxProfile();
        fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
        fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.download.dir", testDir);
        fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.download.defaultFolder", testDir);
        fxprofile.SetPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "applicati‌​on/pdf,application/x‌​-pdf,application/oct‌​et-stream");

        Driver = new FirefoxDriver(fxprofile);
```

I am using the above preference in my  firefox profile. but still when i donwload the file, i am getting the window prompting me to save the file.

Comment: what kind of file/files (file extensions) you want to download?

Comment: I want to download pdf files